# Get the t function to work in a custom php file

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I am having a custom hand coded PHP page within a Drupal module that loads in a fancybox.
I want the Drupal t() function to work in it. What should I include in the file to make it function?

Comment: Are you including the PHP file from a module?

Answer (score 2):

Include these lines in your php file

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());

include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

Comment: If the page is loaded from a module, I would imagine that Drupal is already bootstrapped, surely?

Comment: I guess that depends on how he includes the file. His question is a bit vague about how that is handled. If he, for example, has a php file as a POST callback and the file just happens to be in the module directory, then it wouldn't get any Drupal functionality at all.

Comment: @hampusn This is what esafwan asked.

Comment: @Mathankumar The question doesn't actually state if the file is loaded through Drupal or just with a standard `require/include` call.

Answer (score 0):

By default the [t()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/7) function is accessible from any custom module.

You shouldn't have to include any other files/code.